# ag-grid: How to render standalone chart using ChartModel generated by getChartModels()?

Tags: javascript, charts, ag-grid

After user generate their own chart using UI in ag-grid (data table), I am saving the chart model generated by method `getChartModels()` - this method is described [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-charts-integrated-chart-range-api/#saving-and-restoring-charts) and demo is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/2fVPgFH6LdH7bWUA).

So, I can save and next restore the chart model in [Integrated chart mode](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-charts-integrated-overview/) (data table with chart).
Can I restore the same chart model in [Standalone charts](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-charts-overview/) (ag-Charts)?

Comment: you cant feed the chart model directly to stand alone chart since both are different. chart model do not contain any data just chart settings and references to grid column and rowIndexes so you do need the grid or some method to store chart data as well which you can feed to standalone chart api.